# Reshape numeric matrix using multiple factors with base functions

Tags: r, matrix, reshape

I would like to `reshape` a numeric matrix into a `long` data frame, and include additional conditions.

Rows of the matrix == genes == clusters

Columns of the matrix == samples == time

```
# matrix
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(50), ncol=10)

# factors
genes <- letters[1:nrow(mat)]
clusters <- c(1,1,1,2,2)
samples <- rep(c("A","B"),times=5)
time <- rep(c(0,2,4,5,7),each=2)
```

I tried the following:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(mat, varnames=c("genes","samples"))
df$clusters <- clusters[df$genes] # numeric
df$time <- time[df$samples] # numeric
df$genes <- genes[df$genes] # character
df$samples <- samples[df$samples] # character

> head(df)  
    genes  samples     value    clusters  time
1     a       A      0.25331851     1      0
2     b       A     -0.02854676     1      0
3     c       A     -0.04287046     1      0
4     d       A      1.36860228     2      0
5     e       A     -0.22577099     2      0
6     a       B      1.51647060     1      0
```

Is there more efficient (and faster) way to reshape this without coercing the strings into factors? If possible, I would prefer to use base function, but any other examples are also welcome.

PS: I understand that this issue may have been iterated extensively throughout this site, which I have browsed and unfortunately failed to adopt a potential solution due to limited understanding on how these functions operate, hence any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could set `rownames(mat) <- letters[1:nrow(mat)]; colnames(mat) <- rep(c("A","B"),times=5)` before `melt`ing. However, `melt.matrix` calls `type.convert` with `as.is=FALSE`, so coercion to factors cannot be avoided if you do this.

Comment: @Roland, thank you for the suggestion. Although I get a data.frame with `genes` and `samples`, but then I have no means of assigning `time` and `clusters`. By keeping the row and colnames blank I can use their respective indices to assign all the factors in the resulting data.frame, but I am not sure if it's the right/best way though.